# Why am I getting a cast error in my Query using JDO on Google App Engine?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jdo, jdoql

According to [the Queries and Indexes doc](http://code.google.com/intl/pl/appengine/docs/java/datastore/queriesandindexes.html#Introducing_Queries) you can go a query effectively identically (so far as I can tell) to this:

```
PersistenceManager pm = PMF.get().getPersistenceManager();
try {
    Query q = pm.newQuery(App.class);
    q.setOrdering("name desc");

    try {
        results = (ArrayList<App>) q.execute();
    } finally {
        q.closeAll();
    }
} finally {
    pm.close();
}
```

However, I'm getting the following error on the `results = (ArrayList<App>) q.execute();`
 line:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.datanucleus.store.appengine.query.StreamingQueryResult cannot be cast to java.util.ArrayList
    at com.killerrobots.AppSite.MainServlet.getApplications(MainServlet.java:66)
    at com.killerrobots.AppSite.MainServlet.doGet(MainServlet.java:26)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:693)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:806)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:487)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1093)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:43)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1084)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:360)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:181)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:712)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:405)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.DevAppEngineWebAppContext.handle(DevAppEngineWebAppContext.java:54)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:139)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService$ApiProxyHandler.handle(JettyContainerService.java:306)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:139)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:313)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:506)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:830)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:514)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:211)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:381)
    at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:396)
    at org.mortbay.thread.BoundedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(BoundedThreadPool.java:442)
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can cast the result of `execute` to a `List<whatever>`, but **not** specifically to an `ArrayList<whatever>` which is what your code is trying to do!  Why not just use `List`, the abstraction you're allowed to cast to, rather than `ArrayList`, the concrete implementation that you're *not* allowed to cast to?

Comment: Crap... I knew I'd been looking at the code too long. Missed the obvious. Thanks.